# How to link the pairs of values from 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table [tt] with 2 columns which has a set of values that can repeat.
Columns are named [a] and [b]:

```
[a] [b]
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   1
2   3
3   2
4   1
4   5
5   4
5   6
```

I know how to query only the pairs:

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B
    FROM tt AS t1
INNER JOIN tt AS t2
    ON t1.A = t2.B AND t1.B = t2.A
```

But how can I link the pairs together with adding a new column [pair_id] f.e. like this:

```
[a] [b] [pair_id]
1   2   1
2   1   1
1   4   2
4   1   2
2   3   3
3   2   3
4   5   4
5   4   4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `dense_rank` function ordered by least and greatest functions.

```
select a, b,
  dense_rank() over (order by least(a, b), greatest(a, b)) pair_id
from tbl
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZmOrc1SF)